# Noisy out from the PLL

Tags: noise, pll, vco

I have designed a PLL using an [ADF4106](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4106.pdf) and a [VCO](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/94/CVCO33CL_0110_0150-2303240.pdf). I have taken references from [CN0290](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0290.pdf).

I am able to get the desired output from the design, but there are other unwanted peaks in the output.

I have designed the loop filter using the ADSimmPll tool from Analog Devices.

How can I reduce these spurs/unwanted peaks from the output?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Tesla23 Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Looking at the top spectrum, the peaks are about 45 dB down on the wanted signal so that isn't too bad at all. Maybe you see something different?

Comment: @Andyaka I am expecting a clean noise floor.

Comment: 45 dB down is like comparing 1 volt against 5.62 mV. The 5.62 mV signal is small compared to 1 volt.

Comment: Spurs can come from the dividers. I've seen a scheme to reduce the noise from prescalers by running them with different ratios that add up to the same thing. (like 1/2 = 2/4, but the counter takes 2x the time on the second setting), or even switching the ratios at high speed. Also, what is the noise coming from the oscillator alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that the PLL seems to be locked and producing 122.88MHz,  although I'm not sure what I am seeing in the different plots.

What are you actually measuring?  Is it just the output of your PLL or is there some PA involved (the power on some is showing as 27dBm)?  I'll assume that you are looking at the output of the VCO and that we don't have some oscillating PA.

The spectrum is so bad that it's difficult to see your PLL producing it.  Spurs produced by a PLL tend to be symmetric around the carrier (as they are the result of phase/frequency modulation), these aren't so I'd suspect the measuring setup,  or possibly your layout is so bad that there are multiple interfering signals entering.  I know very little about Signal Hound devices, they seem to be a SDR dressed up as a spectrum analyzer.  A very good SDR would make a good spectrum analyzer, but the sort of common low-cost SDR dongles wouldn't.  I have no idea what's inside the Signal Hound, but a couple of comments I read on their website make me wary of it.

Have you got a clean 122.88MHz signal that you can feed into your Signal Hound to see how good it actually is?  Can you borrow a good spectrum analyzer?

Put an attenuator, say 10dB, between your PLL and the spectrum analyzer.  Anything that doesn't drop 10dB is probably not you. Anything that drops >10dB is a higher order mixing product due to overdriving the spectrum analyzer.  Anything that drops 10dB could still be a spur generated in the spectrum analyzer, just first order.

If your PLL is producing spurs, the usual culprits are noise on the VCO power supply,  noise on the supply to the ADF4106 (particularly the charge pump), and poor grounding / long leads allowing pickup in the charge-pump output to loop filter to VCO circuitry.

**Update:**
I've just looked at the SA124B specification [User Manual](https://signalhound.com/sigdownloads/SA124B/SA124B-User-Manual.pdf).  This is an interesting device, and probably very useful, but you need to use it with care.  Unlike a traditional spectrum analyzer, it has several characteristics that can catch you out.  Most obvious is the spurious response spec.  Read it carefully - it has NO spurious specification once your span exceeds 100kHz.  For spans less than 100kHz, the spurs are below -80dBm.  This means that for your wideband sweeps,  all the extra signals you see could be spurs!  What you can do, I guess, is tune the SA to the frequency of each spur that may be there, and check with a span < 100kHz to see if it is actually there.

Comment: I need 122.88MHz output. I wanted to make sure if peaks existed at other frequencies not only 122.88, hence measured at different frequencies. I will check output once with the Anritsu spectrum analyzer once.

Comment: You're very wise to check.  I'd be worried if the output really had those other peaks, it would be a sign of something very wrong.  I don't know what you really need, but there is no way that if your circuit is working properly that you should have a spectrum like that.  Just ignore those who think -40dB is OK,

Comment: You're right. I checked with Spectrum Analyzer, no peaks/spurs were observed in the output.

Comment: Well done - so it works!

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference of approximately 40 db. Do you want to reduce it more? If so, there is no other way to use a filter by passing on the desired bandwidth.